tables side by side
I want to create this table, but unfortunately, I have no idea whether I should make two separate tables and arrange them side by side, or if it would be better to write them in a single table. On the left side, there are two photos in individual cells.


I'd make two tables and use minipages to arrange them side by side.

Sorry, but this question is not really focusing on TeX and hence off-topic. But you might want to improve it by showing some code and more clearly stating what your problem related to (La)TeX is.

Welcome to TeX.SE
As you are not providing any MWE, I've just shared my ideas only
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
.... first table matter
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
....second table matter
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

